# Unity 3D C# Script - Button loading new scene code error

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(-36, 79, 83, 31), "Play"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }
}
```

This code does exactly what I want it to do, make the 'play' button, bring me to scene 1 (starting out from the main menu, scene 0)
BUT, for some reason (I am new to coding, may have did something wrong, obviously) it makes a new play button and applies it to that button (idk how it does that xD I wasn't even trying to make it make a new button) but anyways, I want it to apply to the already existing play button that I added.

Comment: I advise you look at this before moving forward... http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want the button to go away after it is clicked? To do that you could do something like:

```
private bool levelLoaded = false;
void OnGUI()
{
    if (!levelLoaded && GUI.Button(new Rect(-36, 79, 83, 31), "Play"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
        levelLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Clicking the button would set `levelLoaded` to `true`. If `levelLoaded` is true, the script will never reach the part where it draws the button again.